# ggplot2: negative bar chart with dual x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce chart like this:
[image]

I go with this code:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  name1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  name2 = c("F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
  value = c(-12,10,5,-7,-2)
)

ggplot(dat,aes(x = name1,y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           fill = "#465978",
           width = 0.3) +
  ylim(-50,50) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,
             color = "#9e9e9e",
             alpha = 0.3,
             linetype = "dotted") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "#737373"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

and ended up like this: (note: there is a line in the middle, if you can't see, may be due to low resolution)

[image]

How to add `dat$name2` in the right side (i.e. top x axis)?

If you don't mind, maybe you can help me produce more similar chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offering an alternative to r2evans' solution, you can convert a discrete variable to a continuous one by doing `match(x, unique(x))`. If you then have continuous variables on both axes, it is easy to add a secondary axis.

Here is how you could do that (with some extra decorations based on your request to make the chart more similar).

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
  name1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  name2 = c("F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
  value = c(-12,10,5,-7,-2)
)

# Probably easiest to define `cont_name1 = match(name1, unique(name1))` in the data
# instead of having to declare it in the `aes()` every time.

ggplot(dat,aes(x = value,y = match(name1, unique(name1)))) +
  geom_tile(width = Inf, height = 0.3, fill = "grey95") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           fill = "#465978",
           width = 0.3, orientation = "y") +
  geom_segment(aes(y = match(name1, unique(name1)) - 0.15,
                   yend = match(name1, unique(name1)) + 0.3,
                   xend = value)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = ifelse(value < 0, value - 4, value + 4),
                y = match(name1, unique(name1)) + 0.2,
                label = scales::percent(value, scale = 1, accuracy = 1)),
            vjust = 0) +
  xlim(-50,50) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = match(dat$name1, unique(dat$name1)),
    labels = dat$name1,
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .x, labels = dat$name2, breaks = 1:5)
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0,
             color = "#9e9e9e",
             alpha = 0.3,
             linetype = "dotted") +
  ggtitle("Title here (0%)") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "#737373"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, colour = "grey60"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Once again, teunbrand, your `ggplot2`-ninja-skills surpass my hacks :-)

Comment: I only know this because I'm frustrated with dealing with a combination of discrete and continuous variables, r2evans :p

Comment: I've been doing this for 6 hours and you solve in 5 minutes xD
I am psychology student and just learnt R for less than a year in my spare time, especially for my thesis. So this is really help me a lot. Thanks @teunbrand

Comment: By the way, I figure out how to find percentile (for percent label) using ecdf, so thanks again.

Comment: To be fair, we didn't have to start from scratch because you've provided a reprex already, so we just needed to figure out the extra bit that was prompting the question. (Which is exactly how all questions should be posted). But keep going @NursahidAssafaat, being able to parse, understand and visualise data is not a bad skill to have!

Answer (score 1):

Normally (with a continuous scale) I'd recommend `scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=...)`. Unfortunately, `scale_discrete` does not yet support it (see https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3171). With that, the two ways to go include `geom_text` and `annotation`s. I'll offer the first.

To make it consistent on both sides, we'll need to remove the axis labels from the left axis. (I find this annoying, but consistency between axes is important to me. If it is not as much to you, then you can reduce some of the changes.)

```r
ggplot(dat,aes(x = name1,y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           fill = "#465978",
           width = 0.3) +
  ylim(-50,50) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,
             color = "#9e9e9e",
             alpha = 0.3,
             linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_text(aes(y = -Inf, label = name1), hjust = 0, colour = "#737373") +  # new
  geom_text(aes(y = Inf, label = name2), hjust = 1, colour = "#737373") +   # new
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),                                      # change
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image: ggplot2 with two sets of labels]

One problem you will run into with multi-line labels (as in your example) is that of alignment. `ggplot2` has a confounded sense of `hjust=`, where it means *both* direction of the text box from the point *and* alignment of the text within the text box. So `hjust=0` means "text goes to the right of the point, and the text is left-aligned". There does not seem to be an easy way to have the text box go to the right of the point (first `geom_text`, on the left-edge) yet have the text right-justified. (I'll be happy if somebody can show an easy way to work around this!)

The workarounds to force that left-edge right-align textbox require knowing a priori the dimensions of the plot so that you can hard-position the text box (not `y=-Inf`, the left-edge) within the plot boundary and hard-code the limits of the plot. (Know that when you *form* the plot, none of the functions know what the dimensions of the rendered plot will be, in user-points, centimeters, or similar.)

---

As an aside, we can add a `geom_text` and `geom_tile` for a couple more features.

```r
ggplot(dat,aes(x = name1,y = value)) +
  geom_tile(height = 90, width = 0.3, fill = "gray90") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           fill = "#465978",
           width = 0.3) +
  ylim(-50,50) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,
             color = "#9e9e9e",
             alpha = 0.3,
             linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_text(aes(y = -Inf, label = name1), hjust = 0, colour = "#737373") +
  geom_text(aes(y = Inf, label = name2), hjust = 1, colour = "#737373") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), vjust = -1.1) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
. + > ggplot(dat,aes(x = name1,y = value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(y = 0), height = 90, width = 0.3, fill = "gray90") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           fill = "#465978",
           width = 0.3) +
  ylim(-50,50) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,
             color = "#9e9e9e",
             alpha = 0.3,
             linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_text(aes(y = -Inf, label = name1), hjust = 0, colour = "#737373") +
  geom_text(aes(y = Inf, label = name2), hjust = 1, colour = "#737373") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), vjust = -1.1) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image: ggplot2 with labels/rects]

Comment: Wow its great. Thanks for your help. This really help me!